# https post in javascript similar to the curl with header and parameters -d with "request" module nodejs npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, post, npm

I want to create HTTP POST in javascript request exactly like in curl below (which is passing some parameters) to a Django server.

```
curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d 'token=Rh7JARH&param_id=2' 'http://localhost:8000/api/test/param_id'
```

Here is my attempt to create the javascript code. Please note I am using the npm "request" module

```
var request = require('request');
var jsonObject = {
    'token': 'Rh7JARH',
    'param_id': 2   
};
var jsonData = JSON.stringify(jsonObject);
let url = "http://localhost:8000/api/test/param_id";  
request.post({
  headers: {
    'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  },
  url: url,
  body: jsonData
}, function(error, response, body) {
  if (error) {
    console.log("error");
  } else {
    console.log("OK");
    var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log(jsonResponse);
  }
});
```

but the token and param_id is a problem, on the server it complaints

```
django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: "'token'"
```

I would like to create the same curl HTTP POST as in javascript using npm request module like in the example. I think I am close, its probably the jsonObject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below should POST the required parameters to the server. I've tested this against my own server and the url-encoded parameters are parsed correctly:

```
const request = require('request');

const headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
};

const options = {
    url: 'http://localhost:8000/api/test/param_id',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: headers,
    body: 'token=Rh7JARH&param_id=2'
};

request(options, (error, response, body) => {
    if (error) {
        console.error("An error has occurred:", error);
    } else {
        console.log("Response:", body);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try by replacing single quotes to double around jsonObject key-value pair.

```
var jsonObject = {
"token": "@#@dasdas!#@$!#",
"param_id": 2   
};
```